# If $f(z)$ is continuous, does it follow that $\left(f(z)\right)^2$ is also continuous?

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Problem Statement**

If $f(z)$ is continuous, does it follow that $\left(f(z)\right)^2$ is also continuous?

**My Try**

The statement is true (?) when $f$ is differentiable, since then $f$ differentiable implies $f$ is continuous, and also implies that $f^2$ is differentiable with derivative $2f{f'}$, where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ (which exists because $f$ is differentiable).

**Query**

Does the statement
$$\left(f(z)\right)^2 \text{ is continuous}$$
still hold when $f$ is not differentiable?  If not, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Yes.  The function $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous, and the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @XanderHenderson.  Kindly write that out as an actual answer so that I will be able to accept it.  =)

Comment: In general, the pointwise product of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, but showing that products are continuous is slightly more difficult than showing that compositions are continuous (compositions are relatively straight-forward, while products require the addition of an intermediate term, such as $+f(x)g(a) - f(x)g(a)$, then some factoring and clever arguments to get an explicit $\delta$.  Either that, or you have to show that multiplication is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ (or the product of whatever your space is with itself), and again use the fact that composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: (continuing) Neither is all that difficult, but both are fiddly, and I am lazy.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The function $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous, and the composition of continuous functions is continuous.  On $\mathbb{R}$, the proof looks something like this:

> **Theorem:**  Let $f : \mathcal{D}(f) \to \mathcal{D}(g)$ be continuous at $a$, and let $g : \mathcal{D}(g) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $f(a)$, where both $\mathcal{D}(f),\mathcal{D}(g) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  Then the composition $g\circ f$ is continuous at $a$.

*Proof:*  Let $\varepsilon > 0$.  Choose $\delta'$ such that $|x-f(a)| < \delta'$ implies that $|g(x) - g(a)| < \varepsilon$, and choose $\delta$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \delta'$.  Then, chasing the inequalities around, for any $x$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$, we have
$$ | (g\circ f)(x) - (g\circ f)(a) | < \varepsilon, $$
which is what we needed to show.

Comment: The proof is essentially the same on $\mathbb{C}$, right @XanderHenderson?

Comment: The proof is essentially the same in any metric space.  Replace $|x-a|$ with $d(x,a)$, and you get the same argument.  Indeed, in more general topological spaces, we can soup up the argument to use open neighborhoods without really changing anything.